# Restrict additional pagehead in sharepoint popup window

Tags: sharepoint

hi i have added additionalpagehead in sharepoint which will run a javascript functions to show some texts. It is working fine in all the sharepoint pages but it is working in sharepoint popup window also. How can i restrict it from popup windows.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code inside PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead placeholder:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var IsDlg = (/[\\?&]IsDlg=([^&#]*)/.test(window.location.href));
if (!IsDlg)
{

//  your javascript code ...

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Alex's answer is this:
You can add an if condition to your function so that it tests if the current document is loaded in a iframe (which how Sharepoint displays its popup window/modal dialog), before doing that is does.

John Chapman contributed this code [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35833/detect-if-modal-dialog-box):

```
var isInIFrame = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? true : false
```